# Reboot and select proper boot device

Tags: boot

I was using `ubuntu 22.04`. Download `debian 11` image and with `balenaHetcher` created bootable USB drive.

`Changed bootable priority to USB`

On step "configure partitions" i understood that i can't install debian on same usb drive which existing installation files... After exiting installation

`Changed bootable priority back to SSD`

Now i can't boot my home OS from SSD disk and see this:

> Reboot and select proper boot device or Insert boot media in selected
> Boot device and press a key

**Question:** What should i do to boot operating system from hard drive?

Now installing debian 11 on another USB. I can mount my ssd and see that files are in place!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `/boot/efi` folder on my SSD with home OS ... It was valuable part of UEFI partition on this disk

Fixed it with:

1. get bootable USB-drive with Ubuntu
2. "Try Ubuntu"
3. mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
4. `ls -l /mnt/boot/efi`

...empty...

Need to make sure about this, otherwise **may be** you just can put boot flag

5. And [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1076535/1614069) really helped me. Worked after repeated step by step